# How to randomize the values in several columns of a dataframe - so that original values or not known when sharing

Tags: r

This is what I think is a common problem one may have. Suppose that I have a dataset that I want to share with someone but I do not want to disclose the product names etc. In the case of this dataset, suppose that I want to randomize the values of the columns: part, site, cust_id, cust_name, region, forecast_group, and, finally, market. How to do this efficiently?

I want to keep the association between the original column values and the modified column values so that I can convert it back. Almost like a message id and a replication ID that a messaging software could use.

What is the desired output? The same dataframe with the column values with some random values (preferably with the same length of the original values) and some sort of association between the original values and the new random values.

I put below an example data in dput format. I hope that this is the correct way to supply the sample dataset.

```
structure(list(date = c("04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", 
"04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", 
"04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", 
"04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17", "04-01-17"), part = c("18423", 
"24643", "24644", "27027", "27028", "29309", "324470-0010", "324470-0010", 
"324470-0010", "324470-0010", "329509-1300", "329559-0010", "329559-0020", 
"329559-0020", "329559-0030", "329583-0010", "34103", "34104", 
"34104", "34104"), site = c("ERDR", "ERNF", "EDXC", "EDXC", "EDXC", 
"EDXC", "EDXC", "EDXC", "ERDR", "ERDR", "EDXC", "ERDR", "EDXC", 
"ERDR", "ERDR", "EDXC", "ERDR", "EDXC", "ERNF", "ERDR"), family = c("HED00028", 
"HED00036", "HED00036", "HED00024", "HED00024", "HED00027", "CED00010", 
"CED00010", "CED00010", "CED00010", "HED00276", "NRT00006", "NRT00006", 
"NRT00006", "NRT00006", "CED00010", "HED00035", "HED00035", "HED00035", 
"HED00035"), cust_id = c("E-Commerce_Americas", "902_4000", "E-Commerce_Americas", 
"E-Commerce_Americas", "944_4000", "E-Commerce_Canada", "E-Commerce_Americas", 
"E-Commerce_Canada", "E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Canada", 
"E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Canada", 
"E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Canada", 
"E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", "902_4000", "E-Commerce_Americas"
), cust_name = c("E-Commerce Americas", "Mexico", "E-Commerce Americas", 
"E-Commerce Americas", "Americas National", "E-Commerce Canada", 
"E-Commerce Americas", "E-Commerce Canada", "E-Commerce Americas", 
"E-Commerce Canada", "E-Commerce Americas", "E-Commerce Americas", 
"E-Commerce Canada", "E-Commerce Americas", "E-Commerce Americas", 
"E-Commerce Canada", "E-Commerce Americas", "E-Commerce Americas", 
"Mexico", "E-Commerce Americas"), region = c("AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", 
"AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", 
"AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", 
"AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS", "AMERICAS"
), forecast_group = c("E-Commerce_Americas", "All_Other_Wholesale_Americas", 
"E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", "All_Other_Wholesale_Americas", 
"E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", 
"E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", 
"E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", 
"E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas", 
"E-Commerce_Americas", "All_Other_Wholesale_Americas", "E-Commerce_Americas"
), market = c("AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", 
"AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", "AM", 
"AM"), quantity = c("2", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1", "30", "2", 
"18", "2", "1", "1", "4", "6", "3", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1"), 
    abc_code = c("EOL", "C", "C", "EOL", "EOL", "EOL", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "EOL", "EOL", "EOL", "EOL", "EOL", "EOL", "EOL", 
    "EOL", "EOL", "EOL")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000024b01af1ef0>)
```

Comment: Would you consider `library(anonymizer); df1[, lapply(.SD, anonymize)]`

Comment: Or if it is just to sample, try `df1[, lapply(.SD, sample)]` it should break the ties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop over the columns, apply the `anonymize` function, return the first 6 characters with `substr`, and assign it to new columns created by appending prefix 'anon_' to the original column names

```
library(data.table)
#devtools::install_github("paulhendricks/anonymizer")
library(anonymizer)
df2 <- copy(df1)
nm1 <- c("part", "site", "family", "cust_id", "cust_name", "region", 
"forecast_group", "market", "quantity")
anon_nm1 <- paste0('anon_', nm1)
 df2[, (anon_nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) substr(anonymize(x), 1, 6)), .SDcols = nm1]
```

-output

```
> head(df2)
       date  part site   family             cust_id           cust_name   region               forecast_group market quantity abc_code anon_part
1: 04-01-17 18423 ERDR HED00028 E-Commerce_Americas E-Commerce Americas AMERICAS          E-Commerce_Americas     AM        2      EOL    6a57ed
2: 04-01-17 24643 ERNF HED00036            902_4000              Mexico AMERICAS All_Other_Wholesale_Americas     AM        2        C    e81170
3: 04-01-17 24644 EDXC HED00036 E-Commerce_Americas E-Commerce Americas AMERICAS          E-Commerce_Americas     AM        3        C    a34407
4: 04-01-17 27027 EDXC HED00024 E-Commerce_Americas E-Commerce Americas AMERICAS          E-Commerce_Americas     AM        1      EOL    0b2bd4
5: 04-01-17 27028 EDXC HED00024            944_4000   Americas National AMERICAS All_Other_Wholesale_Americas     AM        2      EOL    d91428
6: 04-01-17 29309 EDXC HED00027   E-Commerce_Canada   E-Commerce Canada AMERICAS          E-Commerce_Americas     AM        1      EOL    b9067e
   anon_site anon_family anon_cust_id anon_cust_name anon_region anon_forecast_group anon_market anon_quantity
1:    406c1d      ec7a16       603d29         eb0da1      e6943d              603d29      df0785        de855e
2:    4ca838      740420       8cb50d         fe4c6a      e6943d              16947f      df0785        de855e
3:    396de1      740420       603d29         eb0da1      e6943d              603d29      df0785        c170da
4:    396de1      7ff174       603d29         eb0da1      e6943d              603d29      df0785        51f2e9
5:    396de1      7ff174       3e8856         0aefe7      e6943d              16947f      df0785        de855e
6:    396de1      bfbe64       50fcbf         ef1088      e6943d              603d29      df0785        51f2e9
```

Comment: I think if you add a seed argument to the annonymizer it will retain a relationship to the original so you can decode it per the request of OP.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this suggestion and I will try it. Two questions I have. 1) I cannot install this anonymizer package through regural RStudio channels. 2) The anonymized values are so imposing. Is there any way I can limit them to something like 6 characters for example? Thank you again!

Comment: @SatishVadlamani Do you have `library(devtools)` installed

Comment: If you can kindly tell me how to install this anonymizer or tell me a simpler way to do this so that it is not so imposing, that will be great :)

Comment: Sorry. I see that you showed a line on how to install. Let me try it.

Comment: @SatishVadlamani Do you get any error with `install.packages('anonymizer')` then only you have to install the github version

Comment: @SatishVadlamani added the `substr` to limit to 6 characters

Comment: p.s. I was able to install devtools and anonymizer. Going to next step. Would appreciate snippet code that will randomize but not imposing ;)

Comment: @SatishVadlamani can you check my update output